# How to configure Prometheus Client Library for Java in Eclipse project with Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, prometheus

I would like to use the [Prometheus Client Library](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/clientlibs/) for [Java or Scala](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java) as part of an Eclipse project with Java and configure the library with Maven.

Its implementation contains `pom.xml` files, so configuration with Maven should be possible. I have not found out which group id, artifact id, and version I have to specify, though. Trying the values I found in the aforementioned `pom.xml`files did not work so far.

So how can I configure the Prometheus Client Library for Java (or Scala) as dependecy in my Eclipse project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's example pom usage in [the docs](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java#assets).